# barcode generator in wpf

Tags: wpf, prism

What the best method to genearate barcode in various type in wpf.

Answer (score 6):

Barcode fonts are an easy way to do it, but they can be difficult to deploy because the customer will probably need the font installed on each machine that runs your application.  This can be impractical, particularly for XBAP, Silverlight, and WinPhone7 deployments.

It is quite easy to generate the barcodes yourself in WPF.  Although it can be done in pure XAML, I find it simplest using a mixture of XAML and code.

Start with a converter that takes a character and returns the bar brushes and widths:

```
public class BarcodeConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public static readonly BarcodeConverter Instance = new BarcodeConverter();

  Dictionary<char, string> _codes = new Dictionary<char, string>
  {
    { '0', "nnnwwnwnn" },
    { '1', "wnnwnnnnw" },
    { '2', "nnwwnnnnw" },
    // etc
    { 'A', "wnnnnwnnw" },
    { 'B', "nnwnnwnnw" },
    // etc
  };

  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    string code;
    if(!_codes.TryGetValue((char)value, out code)) return null;

    return
      from i in Enumerable.Range(0, code.Length)
      select new
      {
        color = i%2==0 ? Brushes.Black : Brushes.Transparent,
        width = code[i]=='n' ? 5 : 10,
      };
  }
  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

Now the XAML to construct the bars is trivial:

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="HorizontalPanel">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="SingleBarTemplate">
  <Rectangle Fill="{Binding color}" Width="{Binding width}" />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="SingleCodeTemplate">
  <DockPanel>
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Text="{Binding}" />  <!-- Display character at bottom of code -->
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={x:Static my:BarcodeConverter.Instance}}"
                  ItemsPanel="{StaticResource HorizontalPanel}"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SingleBarTemplate}" />
  </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="BarcodeTemplate">
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                ItemsPanel="{StaticResource HorizontalPanel}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SingleBarTemplate}"
                Height="60" />
</DataTemplate>
```

The BarcodeTemplate can be used with a ContentPresenter to display any string, for example:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="123456789"
                  ContentTemplate="{StaticResource BarcodeTemplate}" />
```

or

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding UPCCode}"
                  ContentTemplate="{StaticResource BarcodeTemplate}" />
```

I would argue that this solution is the "best method" to generate barcodes in WPF because:

1. It is simple and self-contained,
2. It does not rely on a font being installed on the computer, and
3. It can work on any WPF or Silverlight implementation.

Comment: +1 This is an ingenious use of the various parts of WPF. I have no specific use for it, but it's pretty neat!

Answer (score 5):

The following is what I have finally:

```
<Window x:Class="ScratchClient.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="655.85" Width="687"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ScratchClient">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BarcodeConverter x:Key="barcodeConverter"/>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="HorizontalPanel">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SingleBarTemplate">
        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding color}" Width="{Binding width}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SingleCodeTemplate">
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Text="{Binding}" />
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource barcodeConverter}}"
              ItemsPanel="{StaticResource HorizontalPanel}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SingleBarTemplate}" />
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="BarcodeTemplate">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}"
            ItemsPanel="{StaticResource HorizontalPanel}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SingleCodeTemplate}"
            Height="100" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ContentPresenter Name="barcode" Content="*WIKIPEDIA*" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource BarcodeTemplate}">
        <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2"></ScaleTransform>
        </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
    </ContentPresenter>
</Grid>
```

```
public class BarcodeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    //W Wide - Black
    //N Narrow - Black
    //w Wide - White
    //n Narrow - White
    #region code details
    Dictionary<char, string> _codes = new Dictionary<char, string>
    {
        {'0',"NnNwWnWnN"},
        {'1',"WnNwNnNnW"},
        {'2',"NnWwNnNnW"},
        {'3',"WnWwNnNnN"},
        {'4',"NnNwWnNnW"},
        {'5',"WnNwWnNnN"},
        {'6',"NnWwWnNnN"},
        {'7',"NnNwNnWnW"},
        {'8',"WnNwNnWnN"},
        {'9',"NnWwNnWnN"},
        {'A',"WnNnNwNnW"},
        {'B',"NnWnNwNnW"},
        {'C',"WnWnNwNnN"},
        {'D',"NnNnWwNnW"},
        {'E',"WnNnWwNnN"},
        {'F',"NnWnWwNnN"},
        {'G',"NnNnNwWnW"},
        {'H',"WnNnNwWnN"},
        {'I',"NnWnNwWnN"},
        {'J',"NnNnWwWnN"},
        {'K',"WnNnNnNwW"},
        {'L',"NnWnNnNwW"},
        {'M',"WnWnNnNwN"},
        {'N',"NnNnWnNwW"},
        {'O',"WnNnWnNwN"},
        {'P',"NnWnWnNwN"},
        {'Q',"NnNnNnWwW"},
        {'R',"WnNnNnWwN"},
        {'S',"NnWnNnWwN"},
        {'T',"NnNnWnWwN"},
        {'U',"WwNnNnNnW"},
        {'V',"NwWnNnNnW"},
        {'W',"WwWnNnNnN"},
        {'X',"NwNnWnNnW"},
        {'Y',"WwNnWnNnN"},
        {'Z',"NwWnWnNnN"},
        {'-',"NwNnNnWnW"},
        {'.',"WwNnNnWnN"},
        {' ',"NwWnNnWnN"},
        {'$',"NwNwNwNnN"},
        {'/',"NwNwNnNwN"},
        {'+',"NwNnNwNwN"},
        {'%',"NnNwNwNwN"},
        {'*',"NwNnWnWnN"},
    };
    #endregion

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string code;
        int narrow = 1, wide = 3;
        if (!_codes.TryGetValue((char)value, out code)) return null;

        code += 'n';
        var result =  from i in Enumerable.Range(0, code.Length)
          select new
          {
              color = (code[i] == 'W' || code[i] == 'N') ? Brushes.Black : Brushes.Transparent,
              width = (code[i] == 'n' || code[i] == 'N') ? narrow : wide
          };
        return result;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And I have created an open source control in github: https://github.com/KevinPan/wpf-barcode, please try.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the easiest way is to use barcode fonts. For example:

```
<Window x:Class="BarcodeTest.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Bar Code Test" Height="209" Width="426">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock FontFamily="IDAutomationHC39M" FontSize="30" 
                   SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center">*0123456789*</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This example uses the font "IDAutomationHC39M". The resulting barcode looks like this:

[image]

This web page lists various freeware or shareware barcode fonts: http://www.adams1.com/fonts.html .